# Does changing Django database backend require code modification?

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-orm, django-database

I'm currently using sqlite3 as Django database backend. However I'm looking forward to use MySQL in the future. Does changing database backend require source code modifications such as models.py, forms.py, views.py..etc.(other than files that link Django to DB such as settings.py)

My guess(not sure) : As my codes interacting with database backend are written in python scripts(not SQL) I guess no source code modification will be needed since it means Django automatically generates SQL querys with my python codes that match with current linked database backend.

Comment: Normally not no, unless you are using some features of the Django ORM that are specific to a database like the `.distinct(..)` with field names that only works for PostgreSQL.

Comment: No you don't have to change if you're switching from sqlite to any db but if you're trying to switch from PostgreSQL to any other and you're using any of these [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) then you've to change code.